# User's question answered by that user, using my code. What to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, reputation

I recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891581/4175265) a question, where the user asked a specific question about reading through a folder and grabbing the filenames so that he could modify those files with whatever other code that he had.

I answered the question to his satisfaction, as he pointed out in his comments. Then he modified my code, reposted it as his own answer and accepted *that* answer, while not even upvoting *my* answer. Is there any recourse for this situation? Am I right/wrong to be bothered by this situation?

Comment: FYI: The user does not have enough reputation to upvote posts.

Comment: Well, I think it is a bit far stretched to cal their implementation a copy of yours. At best they got inspired by it and use the `GetFiles` method you offered but beyond that they shared their own implementation. Their action os not in my spirit but the OP is free to answer their own question and to accept the answer that helped them most. Better luck next time. Shrug it off, move on.

Comment: I've seen this happen many times. Yes, it's irritating but what can you do? Let it go.

Comment: That "move on" approach... Although it's probably the only thing left to do, it's still annoying. I wish there could be other things to do other than move on

Comment: @AlonEitan well, sure, but in this case there is a difference in answer quality. If you have written a 4000 characters post with links and code examples just to find it reworded to just not match the plagiarism rules by all means get very angry about that action and see if you can get support in meta. In this particular case? Meh ...

Comment: @rene I guess you're right, but because the OP acknowledged that the  answer work (_"Yup, it works great, thanks"_) then it a bit frustrating

Comment: Left a comment for that OP.

Comment: @rene I see where it's not an exact copy/plagiarism of my code, but the answer that I gave was what he asked for, from my understanding. It's just frustrating. Anyways, thanks for the comments, everybody.

Comment: @honk I thought that the user that asked that question had special rights in that post where he could upvote the answers. I should probably review privileges again.

Comment: Ultimately this is a pain because one of the principles around here is "SO is not a coding service". You have to actually put the work in yourself, answers are not for providing fully functional code but for answering questions. You helped the OP get over where they were stuck, and then the OP went and worked on their whole code (something it's not reasonable to expect an SO contributor to do) and submitted that as an answer. It's debatable how bad that is, but it's not really in the spirit of the Q&A format

Comment: @Nick: As far as I know, an OP can comment on their Q&A even if they don't have 50 reputation. I don't know of any other special rights. A user needs 15 reputation to upvote, no matter on which post.

Comment: One last question, I took a look at that question again this morning and all of the comments are gone except for the one by @rene. Can somebody explain why that would happen?

Comment: @Nick if comments are not constructive, obsolete or too chatty they can be flagged and then removed when reviewed by a moderator. None of the comments existed to improve your question, they were meta commentary at best. That alone is reason to have them purged. Having deleted comments is not held against you unless you have an habit of  only leaving rude/abusive  comments.

Comment: The initial comments on the question itself were questions that I felt helped me to answer the question in the first place. As for the rest, fair enough. Oh well, what's done is done. Thanks.

Comment: No problem @Nick just do know that if you bring a post to meta it does get extra attention form both meta regulars and moderators. Sometimes that results in voting/flagging or other side-effects you didn't anticipate beforehand. Welcome to Meta ... ;)

Comment: Raw deal, the OP was fine to add an answer, but he should have selected yours as correct.  Kinda rude to select his answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you're right to be bothered, but its probably best to just let the matter lie, at least for now. Hopefully if this user persists in such behavior, then they will be penalized, but for now this strikes me as someone who is simply new to the site and does not understand the etiquette here?

Comment: Penalized for what? The OP didn't break any site rules. What would they be getting punished for?

Comment: Maybe "penalized" is too strong a word. We certainly don't want someone *rewarded* for verbatim copying of someone else's answer, right?

Comment: (though I also recognize that in this particular case, this was *not* merely verbatim copying. The OP actually added more detail in their revision of the answer, which I have no problem rewarding.)

Comment: (also, I personally prefer the answer provided by rene below. But I cannot delete my answer since it was accepted. heh.)

Answer (score 9):

Let's be realistic here. The only bit of useful code from your answer that set them in the right direction was:

```
Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
```

That could have fit easily in a comment.

You couldn't have known that the OP oversimplified their problem statement and only mentioned that they need to read a single directory. Which you answered. Turns out the OP has a directory tree with files and subfolders to be processed.

Of course their own implementation *wins* the *helped most award* in that case.

Is it bad luck? Is it malign? Or just uninformed? I would not have done what the OP did, but I see no big problem with it either. They shared their solution and didn't keep it for themselves which is good. Due to their lack of reputation they [couldn't upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). They might have felt that their own answer better reflects the solution that was tersely described in the question.

As the user is relatively new you could have offered a link once to: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) But that is about it. No matter how *acceptable* your answer is, only the OP decides on which answer helped them most, which is the meaning of the accept mark. Don't go down the road of pestering OPs to mark one or the other answer as accepted, not in comments and preferable not on Meta either.

In the end an accepted answer only gains you 15 reputation once. Writing a better competing answer gives you 10 reputation for each upvote. You can still look into possibilities to improve your answer, assuming the OP stands by their accept vote.

Comment: It's my understanding that it's frowned upon to answer questions within the comments... (S.O. tells you this when you try to comment). Also, if he asked for an answer to cycle through all of the subfolders, I would have been willing to provide that answer as well, but he didn't. I realize that my answer really only focused on one specific line of code, and that it really only took a simple Google search to retrieve the answer... but why should that matter?

Comment: I am not exactly looking to cause problems or pester people, I just thought it would be a good idea to ask about it instead of just frustrating myself because of ignorance. Anyways, I appreciate all of the feedback.

Comment: Sure, all true. A comment sometimes helps to verify scope and to check if they honestly didn't find that option. It's the situation and particular question that caught you. I did not search for a dupe yet but I'm sure one will exist. Not much harm done, we're all good.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to the site and don't know the proper procedures on what to do. I simply thought you just upvote the answer that helps the most. However when you provided your answer I did try to upvote your post before I even went onto working on my own solution. However it said that since my reputation is less than 15 it records the vote but does not publicly change the display. So there was nothing I could do. I did click the check mark underneath it though so not sure if that's what you wanted.

There were no other answers so I posted my own solution that goes above what I asked. Sorry for the inconvenience this may have caused you but there was nothing else I could do.

Also I would've just commented on your original post but I need 50 reputation for that as well...

Comment: You do not need 50 reputation to comment on an answer to your own question.

Comment: No I can comment on my own post but I cannot comment on posts made by other people. I mentioned it in my last line that "I would've just commented on your original post", this was directed to OP

Comment: I was talking about commenting on this thread that was made by you, not on the one I made.

Comment: @Dylan `I did click the check mark underneath it though so not sure if that's what you wanted.` That is exactly what I wanted, and no you didn't.